# SSRS Number to time format HH:mm

Tags: reporting-services

I have a question.
I need to convert number in minutes in format `HH:mm`, for example: `40 > 00:40`, `120 > 02:00`,
`1500 > 25:00`, `7200 > 120:00`. I have found many solutions like `=Format(DateAdd("m", (Fields!MYFIELD.Value * 60), "00:00"), "HH:mm")`, but it did not work. Result for this was `(120) > 01:20`. Can you, please, help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a standard hour and minute format you can use this expression:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Minute, Parameters!MinutesField.Value, Today)
```

And then format the textbox using a string like `h:mm tt` in the properties. However, this would not let you get `120.00` from 7200 because there aren't that many hours in a day.

To do specifically what you showed in the example you could use some simple math like so:

```
=CStr(Floor(Parameters!MinutesField.Value / 60)) & ":" & CStr(Parameters!MinutesField.Value Mod 60)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried it and it works great. Thank you very much for your help and wish a nice day :-)